# In Unity GUI, when change button fontsize, how to change button size to wrap text

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

for ex, here is my button:

[image]

I set button fontsize to 50, to button height, I change it > 50 will wrap text, but in button width, I don't know how to calculate text width so cannot determine button width

so how to determine button width to make sure button can wrap its inner text

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution, use `UnityEngine.UI.Text#preferredWidth`  and `UnityEngine.UI.Text#preferredHeight`